# Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor is not an element of this graph

Tags: tensorflow

Tried to predict type of gen, but got some error, could you suggest what's wrong?
any help will be appreciate. In other case to predict type of clothes in ZOLANDO dataset it's works. But in other case I was stuck :(

```
#some code of gen1, gen2 and merged dataFrames
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
    y_train = y_train['y'].values.reshape(1,14000).astype('int32')
    labels_ = np.zeros((14000,2))
    labels_[np.arange(14000), y_train] = 1        
    X_train = np.array(X_train)
    X_train = X_train.transpose()
    X_train = np.where(X_train<0, X_train ** 2, X_train)        
    n_dim = X_train.shape[0]
    ops.reset_default_graph()
    tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
    n1 = 2
    n2 = 2
    cost_history = np.empty(shape=[1], dtype = float)
    learning_rate = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())
    X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(n_dim, None))
    #X = np.array([n_dim, None],dtype="float32")
    Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(n2, None))
    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([n1,n_dim], stddev=.1))
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n1,1]))
    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([n2,n1], stddev=.1))
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n2,1]))
    
    
    Z1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(W1,X) + b1)
    Z2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(W2,Z1) + b2)
    y_ = tf.nn.softmax(Z2,0)
    cost =  - tf.reduce_mean(Y * tf.math.log(y_) + (1-Y) * tf.math.log(1-y_) )
    optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
    init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
   
    ops.reset_default_graph()
    tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
    
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    training_epochs = 100
    
    cost_history = []
    for epoch in range(training_epochs+1):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {X: X_train, Y: labels_, learning_rate: 0.001})
        cost_ = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = { X: X_train, Y: labels_, learning_rate: 0.001})
        cost_history = np.append(cost_history, cost_)
    
        if (epoch % 10 == 0):
            print("Reached epoch",epoch,"cost J =", cost_)
```

got:

> **TypeError:** Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(2, None), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
graph = tf.Graph()    
    with graph.as_default():
        (your code of tf)
```